# Long title on one line

Tags: titles

I'm using this template:
https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-presentation-template/pphckrjbyyzy

The problem is that I have a title that is too long and I am not able to separate it on more lines keeping the same settings.
Indeed if I try to put '\' inside the title the second line results with a different format.

Maybe I need to specify something into the title setting but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use your template, so I can't guarantee this will work, but there is no reason why it should not.

Just use a stack to construct the title and subtitle.  I also show how to set the respective baselineskips, if the default is not correct.

If the top margin seems wrong, try a `\Longunderstack` instead of a `\Longstack`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\title{\setstackgap{L}{22pt}% Set baselineskip if needed
  \Longstack{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in \\
  voluptate velit esse cillum  \\
  dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur}}

\subtitle{\setstackgap{L}{16pt}% Set baselineskip if needed
  \Longstack{lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \\
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et \\
  dolore magna aliqua}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `flux` theme is not behaving well when breaking long lines.

[image: a1]

The same goes for subtitles, which are usually longer.

While it is being fixed you can use this workaround:

```
\title{\\ \Huge Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in \\[0.5em]   \Huge voluptate velit esse cillum  \\[0.5em]  \Huge dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur\\[0.5em]}

\subtitle{\\ \Large lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \\[0.3em] \Large sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et \\[0.3em] \Large dolore magna aliqua}
```

[image: c]

**Note** (not related with the question)

To me the result is nicer if you replace the fonts recommended

```
% Use roboto Font (recommended)
%\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
```

[image: d]